# Google Calendar apis V3 - OAuth2.0 sample code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, google-oauth

I'm new here. Forgive me if there is any rules I didn't follow up and feel free to let me know that.

I am facing some problem about OAuth2.0 authentication when using Google Calendar apis V3.

Here's the code.

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim secret As New ClientSecrets
    secret.ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    secret.ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    Dim init As New Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
    init.ClientSecrets = secret

    Dim flow As New Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow(init)
    Dim token As Responses.TokenResponse = flow.LoadTokenAsync("XXXXXX@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None).Result
    Dim credential As New UserCredential(flow, "XXXXXX@gmail.com", token)


    Try
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secret, {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar}, "user", CancellationToken.None, ).Result
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

It can successfully popup google log in interface

However, It shows up an error message about "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch"

It's weird that I already setup an redirect URL which is

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

in Google Developers Console

But the detail of the error msg shows that redirect URL are not the one I set and keep change the localhost port number.

I think the problem are coming from the line below

```
Dim token As Responses.TokenResponse = flow.LoadTokenAsync("XXXXXX@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None).Result
```

Is something I miss understanding or some parameter I lost it?

Appreciate if anyone could help this out.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I think it goes wrong at the setting of redirect URL which cannot be a localhost site. I suggest you use some URL accessible from the external network instead.

Comment: Second, I also use another code to replace the section about Code Exchange such as below

`token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("user", code, strUri, CancellationToken.None).Result`

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio likes to randomly change the port number.  You can set it up to not do that.  Should be somewhere on the `project properties -> web -> project URL`.

Or

You could go to the Google developers console and create a `Client ID for native application` use this to test on your localhost.

Don't release this one to production when you move it to your website change it back to the `Client ID for web application`